# Doorbell wires are numbered rather than labelled 'Front', 'Rear', & 'Transformer'. Which is which?

Tags: wiring, doorbell

I'm trying to install a Ring Doorbell Pro.

The instructions to connect to the existing doorbell assume that the wires in the chime of the existing doorbell are labeled 'Front', 'Rear', & 'Transformer'.

However, on my doorbell chime they are labelled '1', '2' & '3'.

Is this common? I can't find any other reference online?   Which number corresponds to which label?

[image]

Comment: Disconnect one at a time and test the buttons to see what wire comes from each button.

Comment: I see only two wires there, more are needed for ring.